# Oauth - Facebook/ Twitter / Foursquare

Tags: facebook, twitter, oauth, foursquare

I am creating a way people can connect their Fb, Twitter and FS account to the account they create on my application. I wanna create a single table where i can store all the required stuff..

```
User(id, username, password, email)

Oauth (id, user_id, oauth_provider, ....... )
```

**As for my Understanding**

*Facebook* needs facebook id

*Twitter* needs id, token, secret

*Foursquare* requires email and consumer id.

Just wanted to confirm i am doing it right.. in constructing the Oauth Table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally create a field named "setting_parameter" for the requirement's value because all of these API need different things. As you've said Facebook need App ID (plus Token), Twitter needs Consumer Key and consumer Secret..

All of this value I merge them all into one string with **JSON-format**. I don't put them each into the field because I think there won't be necessary for me to query this table for operations other than get their value. Beside, I need to implemented other APIs in the future. That's why I can't create special field, because I won't know what kind of value the new API will going to need next time. That's why I prefer to squished them into one string field.

The table of mine is like this
`Oauth(id, name, setting_parameter, description,...)`

Comment: can u give me an example of how you will store it in a single string ?

Comment: wont checking the database for a specified user be difficult if the user already has the account ?

Comment: I am working on php(but the concept will work on other language too). First I create array which is like this  `$arr=array('token'=>'somevalue', 'api_id'=>'somevalue');`  And then use json_encode() the array before storing it into the database  Now the field would look something like this `{"token":"somevalue", "api_id":"somevalue"}`    I don't understand why would it be difficult? Mind to explain more detail?

Comment: {"fb_uuid":"xxxxxx", "fb_token":"taken_value"}  say when i want to check if a fb user of the value "234213424" has returned to login. wont it be tough to check if the record is there in the db and then do the needful

Comment: Ah yes.. If you need their social network account to login into your app, then their social account id is better at its own field(for better selection in table).   In my case,   the users have create an user account on my web-app. After creating the account, later they can connect their social network to my app, later my app retrieve these information (e.g: token, user_id) and store them into a table and reference to the table User . That's why having all information merged into one field is no problem for me.

Comment: cool. i am using only Facebook Connect and native Site Registration. So i guess in that case i will need to query the uid :) Thanks for the help :)